# How can I remove an element iteratively from a vector using any Apply functions in R?

Tags: r, vector, indexing, apply

How do I remove an element iteratively from a vector using any of the Apply functions in R?

For example, given that `a = c(1:5)`. I need to remove an element iteratively so that I can obtain a list of the following outputs:

```
2  3  4  5
1  3  4  5
1  2  4  5
1  2  3  5
1  2  3  4
```

How do I go about doing it using any of the Apply functions? As the number of elements in the vector is very large, the for-loop takes a very long time to generate the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
alist <- lapply(1:length(a), function(as) {
    a[-as]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use an `apply` function, you can use

```
t(sapply(a, setdiff, x=a))
```

We need to use `t()` to transpose because `sapply` prefers to return results in column order.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can remove one element at a time with laply:

```
library(plyr)
laply(1:length(a), function(x) a[-x])

     1 2 3 4
[1,] 2 3 4 5
[2,] 1 3 4 5
[3,] 1 2 4 5
[4,] 1 2 3 5
[5,] 1 2 3 4
```